# Add random custom posts to the wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a problem Im trying to solve and not having much luck, Iv tried google/stackoverflow etc, but all I find in general 'random post' type answers

here's the issue:

I am getting my posts using a pretty standard loop

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php $cat = get_the_category();
    if(strtolower($cat[0]->name) != 'hidden'){
  ?>
```

I then display all the post data etc, etc.

I have a custom post type, with an option in the back end to limit the number of these custom posts that can be shown on the homepage

```
get_option('max_amount')
```

What I want to do is mix some of the custom posts (custom post type) in with the posts from the loop, not exceeding the 'max_amount' BUT I dont want them next to each other, I need them mixed in.

Hope that all makes sense and someone can help or point me in the right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the posts to and array you could then use `shuffle($posts)` to randomise the post. Then use `$posts = array_slice($posts, 0, get_option('max_amount')` to ensure you don't exceed the max amount.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end I got the posts and my custom posts in 2 different arrays and merged and shuffled. worked great